# override ember-data's url conventions

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In my ember-app I have this model:

```
//models/photo.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
    image: DS.attr(),
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    caption: DS.attr('string'),
    published: DS.attr('boolean')
});
```

Then I have to fetch data for it from a REST api; in particular the photo model should be fecthed from 2 endpoints in this way:

- route /aaa --> should fetch from /photos endpoint that returns an array of all photos;

this is easy:

```
var photos = this.store.findAll('photo')
```

and ember-data will automatically call the /photos endpoint, since this follows its conventions;

- route /bbb --> should fetch from /feed; the /feed REST api endpoint returns also an array of photos (same model as above) but filtered in a certain way;

in any case the it returns an array of photos objects, like the /photos endpoint;
but in this case it is not possible to do

```
var photos = this.store.findAll('photos')
```

as in the /aaa route, since doing this will tell ember-data to fetch from /photos endopoint;

How can I fetch the same model from different endpoints in different routes?
(I use ember 2.2.0 with ember-data 2.2.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that unless you're doing a plain ol ajax call and push the payload to store or patch the adapter. I wouldn't recommend messing with ember data and its adapter as it will definitely come back to bite you. What you could do is pass in a parameter and change the logic in the API controller to do a if/else check on that param and send the relevant data that you need.

Route 1 - `this.store.query('photo', { type: 'png' })`

Route 2 - `this.store.query('photo', { type: 'jpeg' })`

Comment: Can you be more specific about why pushing the payload of an Ajax call into the store would be such a bad idea?

Comment: Not a bad idea as such, but when you are using a framework, it is best to stick to the confines/conventions of that particular framework. 

One of the reasons is because you'll have to take care of structuring the data to push to store, and that requests will be made everytime you move in and out of the page, instead of taking it from store.

Ember guides will guide you better - https://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/wip/basic-ajax/

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can't because adapters are per model, not per route.

To get around this, however, you can use a plain ajax call paired with `store.push`/`store.pushPayload` to load the data into the store.

See the [store documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_push) for further details.